# Библиотека по генерации QR кода для пхп не подключается

Tags: php, laravel, library, qrcode

[PHPQRcode](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) Достаточно проста в применении, если использовать "процедурально".
Но я хотел использовать её вместе с Laravel. 
Используя код напрямую в view - я её подключаю просто:

```
include(base_path() . '/app/Http/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
```

И далее нужный мне код для отображения QR-кода.

Но когда я хочу воспользоваться библиотекой в классе (то есть вынести весь код из `view.blade` в отдельный контроллер), то получаю ошибку:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\QRcode' not found
```

эта строка в коде выдаёт ошибку:

```
QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempDir . $user_id . '.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 4);
```

**Controller**:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\UsersData;

class GenerateQRCodeController extends Controller
{
    public function generate()
    {
        include(base_path() . '\app\Http\Controllers\phpqrcode\qrlib.php'); // По идее тут как-то буксует
        $user_id = \Auth::id();
        ...
        QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempDir . $user_id . '.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 4);
```

Всё содержимое **qrlib.php**:

```
<?php
    $QR_BASEDIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    // Required libs

    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrconst.php";
    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrconfig.php";
    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrtools.php";
    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrspec.php";
    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrimage.php";
    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrinput.php";
    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrbitstream.php";
    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrsplit.php";
    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrrscode.php";
    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrmask.php";
    include $QR_BASEDIR . "qrencode.php";
```

Искал и пробовал разные варианты: artisan cache clear, config clear, include, namespace, composer require, composer classmap

как оказалось, такая же ситуация обстоит и с другой библиотекой:

```
include(base_path() . '/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php');
```

так же в этом классе `GenerateQRCodeController`

**UPDATE 31.03**

вопрос с php QRcode библиотекой решён!  Оказывается в контроллере надо использовать `use PHPQRCode`. Это namespace, который находится в папке `vendor/автор библиотеки/phpqrcode/lib/PHPQRCode/QRcode.php`. 
И в строке добавить `\PHPQRCode`

```
\PHPQRCode\QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempDir . $user_id . '.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 4);
```

так же, без

```
include(base_path() . '\app\Http\Controllers\phpqrcode\qrlib.php');
```

не будет работать.

Не очень интуитивно понятно, почему так происходит. Ну да ладно.
А вот со второй библиотекой Image по такому же принципу пока не получилось.

**2 UPDATE 31.03**

С Image тоже получилось: 
по аналогии `use Intervention\Image` не сработало, а нужно было `use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;`
и всё... 
а тут, кстати, `include` можно убрать из контроллера.

ничего не понимаю, почему так разительно всё отличается...  проще конечно было оставить пхп код в `view.blade`  и не мудрить  с  этим контроллером...

Comment: Просто разберитесь с ООП в PHP, сразу всё станет понятно...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar это понятно, что я мало в чём разбираюсь, и понятно, что на русском stackoverflow любят подкалывать и, по возможности унижать. Просто ваш комментарий тут абсолютно неуместен, по крайней мере в такой язвительной форме.

Comment: @a-volg А в чём унижение? Просто говорю, что в документации везде всё хорошо расписано. Вы это скорее всего прочитали, раз апдейтнули вопрос (кстати, можно было бы ответить самому себе - было бы полезнее для других). Подходы к программированию принципиально разные - нужно сначала разбираться, а потом уже задавать конкретные вопросы. Т.е инклюдить класс в метод класса, а потом пытаться забрать методы класса, в котором Вы находитесь, нельзя.

Comment: "Оставить пхп код во вьюхе". А че сразу-то все во вьюху не засунуть? Сессию там стартовать, коннект к бд открыть, запросы гонять. Зачем ларка-то вообще тогда?

Comment: @u_mulder а чем плох пхп во вьюхе?

Comment: В модели MVC вьюха выводит данные на экран. Это __всё__, чем она должна заниматься. И она понятия не имеет что есть какие-то классы и прочие зависимости. Какой смысл размазывать логику между контроллером и вьюхой? Не только про ООП надо почитать, но и про суть модели MVC.

Comment: какое-то вы агрессивное сообщество, я вам скажу. После западных особенно это чувствуется.

Comment: @A.Volg сообщество не агрессивное, а менее склонное к сглаживанию угловатостей, успокаивания и поднятию вашего чувства безопасности. Мы отвечаем по сути, может, и не всегда в правильном тоне или интонациях, но стараемся чтобы при подаваемых ответах автор продолжал размышлять и делать выводы, не выдавая всё сразу на блюдечке, да ещё и с горкой сверху. Для ищущих готовый ответ сразу это недостаток, для мыслящих самостоятельно и понимающих такой подход - это преимущество, пусть и не бросающееся в глаза.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov  о да!  первый коммент особенно подходит под Ваше описание "Просто разберитесь с ООП в PHP, сразу всё станет понятно."

Comment: @A.Volg ещё раз, если вопрос не-конкретный, и у автора нет четкого представления о базовых вещах, используемых во фреймворке, то и советуется то, что по нашему мнению подойдёт для изучения по теме вопроса и его дальнейшего уточнения.